# Question closed as off-topic for requesting external resource recommendation. But it doesn't

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I don't understand the close reason for that question:

- [What is the meaning of the FORCE keyword in a CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696018)

It was closed because *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"* with at least 4 votes for that reason. But the OP *isn't* requesting recommendation for any off-site resource.

Please note that I don't argue about the quality or the need to close that question. But about the reason given.

Comment: My guess is that someone just chose the wrong close reason, and everyone else blindly followed and chose the same reason.

Comment: I agree that close reason makes no sense. What I suspect happened is that they really wanted to close it for "lack of research effort" but that close reason doesn't actually exist (anymore) so they just picked one.

Comment: @BSMP I could understand that. But in that case, it should have been down-voted for _"lack of research effort"_ instead... and probably with a comment explaining that. As of now, it doesn't provide any clear feedback to the OP (and other visitors) on what was "wrong" with the question and how to improve his future experience with StackOverflow.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - I wasn't arguing that it was a good thing to do, just that I think that's probably what happened. I agree that the close reason does not apply here.

Comment: Could the [sql] community finally be pushing back against "Can you Google this for me" questions?  It's possible.

Comment: It's an awful question that asks for the meaning of a keyword, with exactly the same text in the title and body. The OP probably should be looking at a tutorial.

Comment: @JonasCz that's quite likely, see [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773)

Comment: It's highly unlikely this is covered in any tutorials @bill. It is right there in the documentation though...

Comment: The close reason is sometimes just the best approximation of the actual reason that turns up in a quick check of the available prewritten choices, alas...

Comment: TL;DR: a crap question got closed for a crap reason. What's the problem here? Be happy the junk was closed and just delete it ASAP. And if you're concerned about not giving OP the correct feedback, feel free to leave some comments explaining why the question is crap and what they should do _before_ asking on SO - IMO that has a way higher chance to actually get OP to listen than any canned messages from the closure.